# Rails - how to find all rows where a certain column value is nil with where()

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to return an array with all rows in a table called `bookings` where the column `returned_date` is empty.

So far I've tried `Booking.where("returned_date <> ''")`, which chose all the records where returned_date is present, but I want an inverse selection of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean to get with `returned_date` column be `null`:

```
Booking.where(returned_date: nil)
```

Comment: Did not expect it to be that easy. It gave errors when using `Booking.where("returned_date = ?", nil)`. Thanks!

Comment: Makes sense... not sure why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do with the below query

```
Booking.where("returned_date IS NULL")
```

**OR**

You can add a scope in your `Booking` model as

```
Class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :nil_returned_date, -> { where("returned_date IS NULL") }

end
```

Then call it as `Booking.nil_returned_date`