# How to check how many columns are 'nil' in a single row of a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have `Employee` table. We get all columns there are in that table through:

```
Employee.columns.map(&:name)
```

Next, we want to know how many fields are `nil` or empty in a single row.

How can we find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails - how to find all rows where a certain column value is nil with where()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361934/rails-how-to-find-all-rows-where-a-certain-column-value-is-nil-with-where)

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but we want to know how many fields are empty in a particular row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count empty columns in a single row using:

`Employee.find(123).attributes.values.count { |v| v.nil? }`

(just change `123` to your employee id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find the number of columns with nil value in a row:

```
id = 1 // or params[:id]
Employee.find(id).attributes.values.select(&:nil?).count
```

Comment: I'm glad this solution worked for you, can you upvote this answer?